# How can i combine Extent Reports from multiple test runs ?(C#, NUnit)

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I need to run my suite of tests in a particular order due to test dependencies. (Yes i know, but the nature of the application i'm testing means there's no way around it.)
I'm using Extent Reporter to create test reports, tests are written in C# using the nunit framework. 
When i run the tests, the report html file gets overwritten with the new tests results. **The alternative of having multiple reports is no alternative at all.**

I also want to run the tests on Jenkins but again, when running multiple batch commands and multiple playlists, it returns a report of the last tests only.

Is there a way of combining the test results into one report or can anybody see an alternative solution to my problem?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a way around my issue. 
Extent Reports v3 does not currently have a means of appending test reports together. The solution was to revert back to version 2 and use the following code in my reporter class:

```
ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports(file-path, false);
```

This sets the replaceExisting = false.

See the extentReports documentation here:
http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/2/net/#append-to-report

Answer (score 0):

Please check, You might have given same name for each Report. Give different name to each Reports and you will be have each separate report So Reports will be not override.

Comment: Hi, creating mutiple reports doesn't really work with me as it would create 10+ reports and that's not the best case scenario. The aim is to merge the results of multiple reports into one report. Thanks.

Comment: If you are creating multiple reports for each different scenario, Then there is no such scope. Merge report is not scope in Extent Report. You can manage Report with Extent Child Node, Extent parent Node. If you working in single class.